# Lazy<T> really is lazy

Tags: c#

I'm having a problem with `Lazy<T>`, and I cannot work out what the issue is.

I'm returning the content of a cookie, but if I use `Lazy<T>`, it takes 2 goes to authenticate a user. I have some simple code that works first time, but as I said, I can't work out why the `Lazy<T>` method doesn't work as expected.

Here's the 2 snippets - nothing else is different.

Snippet 1 - works correctly

```
public FormsAuthenticationTicket Ticket
{
    get
    {
        var ck = Helper.Context.Request.Cookies[FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName];
        if (ck != null)
        {
            return FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(ck.Value);
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Snippet 2 - need 2 pushes of the button

```
Lazy<HttpCookie> lazyCookie = new Lazy<HttpCookie>(GetCookie);

public FormsAuthenticationTicket Ticket
{
    get
    {
        if (Cookie != null  &&  !string.IsNullOrEmpty(Cookie.Value))
        {
            return FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(Cookie.Value);
        }
        return null;
    }
}

HttpCookie Cookie
{
    get { return lazyCookie.Value; }
}

static HttpCookie GetCookie()
{
    return Helper.Context.Request.Cookies[FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName];
}
```

Both pieces of code are called in exactly the same way from an httpmodule::

```
    public void Init(HttpApplication context)
    {
        context.PostAuthenticateRequest += PostAuthenticateRequest;
    }

    void PostAuthenticateRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var page = Helper.Context.Handler as Page;
        if (page != null)
        {
            StoreUserDetails();
        }
    }

    void StoreUserDetails()
    {
        var ticket = new FormsAuthCookie().Ticket;
        if (ticket != null)
        {
            var identity = new UserIdentity(ticket);
            var roles = Roles.GetRolesForUser(identity.Name);
            var principle = new GenericPrincipal(identity, roles);

            Helper.Context.Current.User = principle;
        }
    }
```

I redirect the user if they are logged in based on the principle user info:

```
            if(User.IsInRole("SuperAdmin"))
                Response.RedirectToRoute("PageAdmin");
```

Using the Lazy code, I have to log in twice to see a result, the first snippet works first time.

Comment: so, what goes wrong? Snippet one doesn't call `GetCookie` so they are not the same.

Comment: IsNotNull is not a method of Lazy<T>. Please show that extension method.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain That's being called on `HttpCookie`, not `Lazy<T>`.  Though that also doesn't define a `IsNotNull` method.

Comment: @Jodrell - snippet1 has exactly the same code as the Getcookie method except that its inline in snippet 1.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain - IsNotNull() == obj != null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code,

```
public FormsAuthenticationTicket Ticket
{
    get
    {
        return new Lazy<FormsAuthenticationTicket>(() =>
            {
                var ck =
                    Helper.Context.Request.Cookies[FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName];
                if (ck != null)
                {
                    return FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(ck.Value);
                }

                return null;
            }).Value;
    }
}
```

Is a direct `Lazy` equivalent of your Snippet 1 code.

Comment: I#ll check it out Jodrell

Comment: @JohnOhara, I know this answer is actually not very helpful but, it will provide that your problem is not with `Lazy` but elsewhere.